# How to add PECL add to windows in PHP

Tags: php, pecl

I downloaded PECL SVM from this link `http://phpir.com/svm` . It contains files:[image]

I added `libsvm.dll` in the folder

> C:\xampp\php

and `php_svm.dll` to the directory

> C:\xampp\php\ext

After that I used codes to use SVM class

```
$data = array(
    array(-1, 1 => 0.43, 3 => 0.12, 9284 => 0.2),
    array(1, 1 => 0.22, 5 => 0.01, 94 => 0.11),
);

$svm = new SVM();
$model = $svm->train($data);

$data = array(1 => 0.43, 3 => 0.12, 9284 => 0.2);
$result = $model->predict($data);
var_dump($result);
$model->save('model.svm');
```

but it shows an error like this:

> Warning: require(SVM): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>
> > C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis Project\ndcg_calculation.php on line 18